# How can I diagnose an error in using jQuery file upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to achieve an iframe transport file upload, using the [blueimp file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) as follows:

```
$(jQueryUploadInput).fileupload();
$(jQueryUploadInput).fileupload('send', {
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        fileUpload: profilePicInput,
        url: $.acme.resource.links.editProfilePictureUrl
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    })
    .success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        debugger;
    });
```

When I debug the view that needs the file upload, the `debugger` call inside my `error` function is hit, but all three parameters are undefined, as if the error function was invoked for no reason. `profilePicInput` is a valid file input with one selected file. The action pointed to by `$.acme.resource.links.editProfilePictureUrl` is a valid action url, but a breakpoint in my controller never even gets hit. I also have no idea how to proceed.

I know the API doc says:

> The fileInput property must be a jQuery collection with an input of
>   type file with a valid files selection.

so I have tried both ways of setting the `fileUpload` option, with the same result.

```
fileUpload: profilePicInput
fileUpload: $(profilePicInput)
```

Just BTW, this code is being called inside a view model script, not directly in the view itself, if that might mean or affect anyhting. I don't see how, because the viewmodel script is loaded into the view anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem:

- [jquery file Upload rails "Error Empty file upload result"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399652/jquery-file-upload-rails-error-empty-file-upload-result/22399752#22399752)
- [blueImp/jquery file upload - How do I get the error message if the file type was not accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506459/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-how-do-i-get-the-error-message-if-the-file-type-was/16736899#16736899)
- [Passing the error message to jQuery File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097522/passing-the-error-message-to-jquery-file-upload/8121212#8121212)
- http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/25570742-How-to-display-error-messages-when-client-side-validation-fails-

The last link advises the following:

```
processalways: function(e,data){
  if (data.files.error) alert(data.files[0].error);
}
```

You can also access any of the other `Processing Callback Options`. See the [API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#processing-callback-options).

Any processing failure for an individual file can, for example, also be checked with the [processfail callback](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#processfail)

```
function (e, data) {
    console.log('Processing ' + data.files[data.index].name + ' failed.');
}
```

I hope that answers your question. If I didn't understand your question correctly, please let me know.

Comment: You do seem to have understood my question, but I don't understand why, if there is an error with an individual file should `processfail` yield any more error information than `error`? I suppose that answer lies at the end of another long night on this problem.

Comment: @ProfK: But have you tried it? I thought that maybe it's due to the JSON format of the error message..